# Как статически подключить скачанную библиотеку XLNT в VS2017

Tags: c++, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста! по вопросу подключения статически сторонней библиотеки:

1)Скачал библиотеку xlnt для работы с екселем -https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt. 
2)Скачал Cmake, установил, запустил по Windows: 
-в запущенном Cmake строке "Where is the source" указываю путь к скаченной библиотеки XLNT с файлом CMakeLists.txt: C:/11/xlnt-master/xlnt-master/source ---потом указываю путь для "Where build the binaries" и нажимаю Generate.
3)Cmake создает проект для VS2017.
4)Загружаю этот проект в VS2017, и нажимаю "собрать" этот проект. VS2017 создает много файлов, среди который есть .lib файл, по идее файл статической библиотеки, 5)Создаю новый пустой проект в VS2017, там в свойствах проекта указал путь к .lib файлу, указываю #include xlnt.h, нажимаю компилироваться, но VS2017 выдает ошибку - "Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует xlntd.dll..".

ВОПРОС:
1)Во первых xlntd.dll - присутствует, но VS2017 почему то его не видит.
2)Но самый главный вопрос в другом, я ведь указал путь к статической .lib - библиотеки и не хочу чтобы библиотека подключалась динамически, я хочу чтобы она подключилась статически.

Что я не так делаю, подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

.dll при сборке линковщик вообще не использует, линкуются всегда только .lib файлы. И нет, расширение .lib вовсе не подразумевает, что это статическая библиотека. В данном случае это библиотека импорта для подключения .dll (которая при сборке не нужна). Чтобы подключать статически вам ее надо сначала собрать как статическую библиотеку.

А еще у вас пропущен пункт про указание директорий с заголовочными файлами этой бибилиотеки в "Additional include directories"

Comment: VTT, да, прошу прощения пропустил пункт по укащанию каталога для .h файлов, но я его сделал, просто забыл написать.                                                       Подскажите пожалкйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы собрать, как чтатическую библиотеку ?                   Нужно както по другому генерировать проект Cmake'ом для VS или пункт с Cmake'ом не меняется и нужно в VS, как то иначе сборку произвести ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Запустите как `cmake -DSTATIC=ON`

Comment: VTT, подскажите пожалуйста, а куда это "cmake -DSTATIC=ON" вводить ? В Cmake нету поля ввода.

Comment: @Optimus1 В консоль

Comment: VTT, делаю cmake -DSTATIC=ON, но консоль выводит сообщение, что: CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "C:/XLNT/BUILD" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI. Я уже не знаю, как собрать это ***** статическую библиотеку ! :((